# How to access my server MySql from IOS simulator to retrieve data swift

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, mamp

What could be wrong with this code, I'm trying to get into my MAMP sever which is turned on, I have one php file in the server where I'm testing the connections and such, this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
if($_POST) {
    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $password   = $_POST['password'];
    echo $username
    echo $password

    if($username && $password) {

            $db_name     = 'DBTest';
            $db_user     = 'pedro';
            $db_password = 'pedro';
            $server_url  = 'localhost';

            $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

            /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                error_log("Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"' . mysqli_connect_error() . '"}';
            } else {
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ? and password = ?")) {

                    $password = md5($password);

                    /* bind parameters for markers */
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);

                    /* execute query */
                    $stmt->execute();

                    /* bind result variables */
                    $stmt->bind_result($id);

                    /* fetch value */
                    $stmt->fetch();

                    /* close statement */
                    $stmt->close();
                }

                /* close connection */
                $mysqli->close();

                if ($id) {
                    error_log("User $username: password match.");
                    echo '{"success":1}';
                } else {
                    error_log("User $username: password doesn't match.");
                    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Username/Password"}';
                }
            }
    } else {
        echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Username/Password."}';
    }
}else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Data."}';
}
?>
```

And in Xcode The app currently has 3 views all in swift, but the important one is this:

```
//
//  LogInViewController.swift
//  ParkingApp
//
//  Created by Pedro Alonso on 02/06/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Pedro Alonso. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class LogInViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @IBAction func enterTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        var username: String = usernameField.text
        var password: String = passwordField.text


        if ( username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty) {

            var alertView: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Failed"
            alertView.message = "Error in the username or password"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alertView.show()


        } else {

            var post: String = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

            NSLog("Post data: %@", post)
            println(post)

            var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/jsonlogin2.php")!

            var postData: NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!

            var postLenght: String = String(postData.length)

            var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            request.HTTPBody = postData

            request.setValue(postLenght, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

            request.setValue("application/x-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

            var responseError: NSError?

            var response: NSURLResponse?

            var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &responseError)

            if urlData != nil {

                let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!

                println(urlData)

                NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode)

                if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300) {

                    var responseData: NSString = NSString(data: urlData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                    NSLog("Response: ==> %@", responseData)

                    var error: NSError?

                    let jsonData: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSDictionary

                    let succes: Int = jsonData.valueForKey("succes") as! Int

                    if succes == 1 {

                        NSLog("Login Success")

                        var prefs: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

                        prefs.setObject(username, forKey: "USERNAME")

                        prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")

                        prefs.synchronize()

                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


                    } else {

                        var errorMsg: String?

                        if jsonData["error_message"] as? String != nil {

                            errorMsg = jsonData["error_message"] as! String?

                        } else {

                            errorMsg = "Unknown error"
                        }

                        var alertView: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()

                        alertView.title = "Sign in failed"

                        alertView.message = errorMsg
                        alertView.delegate = self
                        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                        alertView.show()


                    }


                } else {

                    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                    alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
                    alertView.message = "Connection Failed"
                    alertView.delegate = self
                    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                    alertView.show()
                }


            } else {

                var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
                alertView.message = "Connection Failure"
                if let error = responseError {
                    alertView.message = (error.localizedDescription)
                }
                alertView.delegate = self
                alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertView.show()
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The .php file is in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs, what is not clear is why is giving me response code 500, and I'm at a lost not sure why is happening. Any help?? Thanks.

EDIT: The response:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fc42149ac60> { URL: http://localhost:8888/jsonlogin2.php } { status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 04 Jun 2015 12:11:35 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.6.7 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zd DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.7";
} }
```

I can access from safari in the simulator to localhost:8888, so there is no connection problem.

EDIT2: So it is the request apparently, because it tells me invalid data skipping all and returning this:

```
2015-06-04 17:16:11.914 ParkingApp[3777:126598] Response: ==> {"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Data."}
```

What could be wrong with the way I've done the request?

EDIT2: I have changed the code and activated the mysql log to see the queries, but still the $stmt->get_result() or fetch() are doing nothing and I do not know why. I'm not doing it throughout IOS but simple browser here is the troublesome part.

Modified part:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

            /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                error_log("Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"' . mysqli_connect_error() . '"}';
            } else {
                $query = "SELECT dataOne,password FROM users WHERE username = ? and password = ?";

                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

                    //$password = md5($password);

                    /* bind parameters for markers */
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);

                    /* execute query */
                    $stmt->execute();

                    //$stmt->debugDumpParams();
                    echo $stmt->sqlstate;
                    var_dump($stmt);

                    /* bind result variables */
                    //$stmt->bind_result($dataOne,$password);

                    $result = $stmt->get_result();

                    printf("test: ", $dataOne, $password);

                     //fetch value

                    while($stmt->fetch()) {

                        echo $dataOne;

                    }


                    /* close statement */
                    $stmt->close();
                }

                /* close connection */
                $mysqli->close();

                if ($result != null) {
                    error_log("User $username: password match.");
                    echo '{"success":1, "dataOne:"'.$dataOne.'}';
                } else {
                    error_log("User $username: password doesn't match.");
                    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Username/Password"}';
                }
            }
```

The $stmt is not retuning anything on the get_result() or is not going into the while(fetch()) I'm just do not know now. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your web server is throwing http error code 500 (Internal Error) it is because your PHP script is crashing. I would try and read the php log, and try and do some debugging of the php script.

Maybe there is something wrong with the posted data from your iOS app, making the php script fail?

Also accessing localhost:8888 from safari in this case would not prove that the php script is working, as it requires you to post any data for the script to execute. `if($_POST) {`. By just browsing that script, the if statement will never be `true`.

EDIT:

It some times helps to verify one component at a time. Try building a simple html form that posts `username` and `password` against your server (`http://localhost:8888/jsonlogin2.php`). When you see this working as expected, move on to making sure the app works. This way you can tell if your errors are on the server (php script) or in your app.

It's also good to check `$_POST` like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {}
```

This will check if the `$_POST`is empty.

Your app is also using `application/x-form-urlencoded` and my guess is that this should be: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

But once again. Make a local html form, and make certain that your php script is working, and then move over to the app.

Comment: Well apparently that error came from the echos $ I'm very rusty in my php I will get into it :)

Comment: And is anyway not executing the if($_POST) {} is just throwing the invalid data error